# Get all administrators of a specific Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Anyone know, if it's possible to get all administrators of a page a user is admin of.
So I can get a list of all the people that have admin permissions to the same Facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't query a page and find all the admins, but the otherwise it's possible, you have a user and get all the pages where he's admin.